# js-ipfs adding file to a node not correctly working

Tags: ipfs, js-ipfs

Hello please help me with this guys
The add method not adding file to directory
This is current status

```
c.files.mkdir("metadata")
c.add([{path:"/metadata/0.json", content:""}]).then((r)=>console.log(r))
This is returned json object
{
  path: 'metadata',
  cid: CID(QmUNLLsPACCz1vLxQVkXqqLX5R1X345qqfHbsf67hvA3Nn),
  size: 4
}
```

Comment: The `cid` returned represents is the hash for a empty directory, it seems that the empty file isn't be created. It seems adding empty files doesn't work right?

Comment: I am not adding empty files

Comment: The code snippet adds an empty file: `content:""` makes the content an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the code with

```
client.files.write('/metadata/name',content,{create:true})
```